# Weird crash when I try to attribute a variable in OpenCV IOS

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

There is something I'm not able to understand. I'm using OpenCV IOS for my IOS Device.

I have a C++ class with a private variable `cv::Rect` . This variable is located to my .h file.
In my .cpp file, I have a method which creates a `cv::Rect`. Then, I would like to attribute this new created cv::Rect to my class variable but It crashs and I do not understand why.

**.h file**

```
class detection {


public:
    detection();

    cv::Mat processImage(cv::Mat frame);

    cv::Mat detectFace(cv::Mat frame);

public:
    cv::Rect getRectangleDetection();
    void setRectangleDetection(cv::Rect& rect);


private:
    cv::Rect _rectangeDetect;

};
```

**.cpp file**

```
    cv::Mat detection::processImage(cv::Mat frame){

    Mat originalColorImage;
    frame.copyTo(originalColorImage);
    int cx = frame.cols/2;
    int cy = frame.rows/2;
    int width = 1000;
    int height = 1000;
    NSLog(@"[INFO] Rectangle creation");

    cv::Rect rect1(cx-width/2,  cy-height/2, width,height);

    cv::Rect test2;
    //test2 = rect1;//It works !

    setRectangleDetection(rect1); // or _rectangeDetect = rect1 --> both don't work

    cv::rectangle( originalColorImage,rect1,
                  cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0),4);



    return originalColorImage;
}
```

I took a look at the crash report and I saw that :

```
exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   detect          0x000000010007f580 cv::Rect_<int>::operator=(cv::Rect_<int> const&) (types.hpp:1689)
1   detect          0x000000010007f504 OpenCV::setRectangleDetection(cv::Rect_<int>) (OpenCV.mm:172) //This is the setter but If I'm not using the setter the error will come from _rectangleDetect = rect1.
```

I tried also to initialize the variable cv::Rect but same behavior.

Do you have any idea what's happen ? Really, I tried to figure out why but without success.
I used a lot OpenCv before and It's the first time something like that happens.

Thank !

Comment: Can you show your code verbatim? `processImage` in your sample code is just a function, not a member of a class while the variable `_rectangleDetect` is a member.

Comment: I added the code. ProcessImage is a function part of my class and _rectangleDetect is a member of my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the problem. It was a silly one.
Actually, on my other class when I was using the detection class, I forgot to initialize the object.

```
Detection _detect = new Detection()
```

As I did not get any error from the following line and by the fact that the behavior seemed to be good (even with some debug), I did not think of that.

```
_detect->processImage(frame);
```

Thank you guys anyway.